# How I can send a message with action button in it with MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using post to webhook for sending message to MS Teams, I need that some messages with button, Is it way to do this rather than CSS or HTML tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhook support Message card in MS Teams.

You can find the sample json [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#example-connector-message).

It will produce below card.
[image]

Comment: I tried it before, When posting this card to webhook, I get an error.

Comment: Can you please share the error you get while posting